# Starting 2 emulators in android

Tags: android-emulator

I was wandering if there was any easy way to start 2 emulators in android. I have looked at the developers guide but theres not enough information to help me. Please could someone explain how this is done. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge you can't start the same emulator twice, but by creating two separate emulators you can start them both at the same time.

You create new emulators using the Android SDK manager's ("SDK Manager.exe", located in your android install directory) "Virtual Devices" tab.

You can then start them in the command prompt using

```
emulator -avd <avd_name>
```

More info here: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am trying to do this so I can run a TCP connection between them but not sure how to set this up. I know I need to somehow create 2 emulators, how can I do this? I need to then use them in cmd, I know the commands to view them is adb devices in cmd. This only shows 1 emulator, cant figure out how to set the second one up. Thanks

Comment: I've edited my answer to answer your questions. Note that to run the "emulator" command your command prompt must be located in the "tools" folder under your Android install directory.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was searching before your answer and came across this which helps: http://wrestlingmind.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-create-two-or-multiple-instances.html