# how to run two emulator parallely in eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Starting 2 emulators in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978179/starting-2-emulators-in-android)

i could not start second emulator when one emulator already running. Actually i want to test chat app on both emulator. Any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: One Simplest Solution can be, you can create two Emulator with same Android Version.

Comment: YOu can use the avd manager to create as many emulators as required and then start them. (how ever starting several emulators would be very task intensive on your machine)

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978179/starting-2-emulators-in-android
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912504/installing-the-same-app-on-two-emulators

Comment: @Lucifer thanks for reply..but can i create two emulator with different version..?? actually two emulator with same version also not worked in my eclipse :(:(

Comment: @KalpeshLakhani, yes why not, but then you need to create two different project for different Android Version, and i guess that will be little tedious job, better you go for same version, that will be easy while deploying.

Comment: @Lucifer..thanks a lot buddy :):)

Comment: Two different projects to have two emulator running different versions? This is nonsense... I have multiple AVDs all running different versions of Android from 2.2 to 4.1. No need for a different project...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your AVD Manager (Eclipse -> Window -> Android Virtual Device manager), select one AVD and press "Start" on the right side.

Comment: ya thats fine but it actually not worked. process shown that its complete but i can not see any other device

Comment: You have defined two separate AVDs?

Comment: yes sir two AVDs one is 2.2 and other is 4.1

Comment: There must be another problem. I could even start two times the same AVD (but get some errors that the file system has problems). Try to create a third one and start that the same way. Btw: Which OS do you us?

Comment: yes agree with u there must be other problem so i accepting your answer..BTW os is windows..thanks

Comment: You can use ADB command for that.http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/starting-and-stopping-android-emulators/